# Missing Value because observation didn't happened

Tags: logistic, missing-data, naive-bayes

I need help how to deal with missing value to fit logistic regression or naive Bayes.

I need to analyze who will likely to purchase the product and I have datasets looks like this. As you can see, purchased day and purchased location are filled up only when purchased = 1. When purchased = 0, the record itself doesn't exist.

In this case, what is the solution for these NA.

[image]

Comment: How do you imagine the time and location of a purchase is going to predict *who* will purchase something? Also, is it impossible for someone to make a purchase twice? I assume not and in that case these aren't independent data.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, there are no NA because in logistic regression your response variable is dichotomic. In your case, 0 for "no purchased", 1 for "purchased".

Comment: @joerna is referring to day and location, not the response.

Comment: I know, but if response variable is 0 for "no purchased" then there's no need to indicate where did occur a no-event. That's how I see the problem, but I think @joerna should tell us if  day and location are considered as explanatory variables